# Unable to deploy ASP.NET MVC 4 app as Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, dll

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app that I'm trying to deploy as an Azure Web Site. My app works fine in my local environment. When I publish the site to azure though, I receive the following error:

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Root'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Views' has found the following matching controllers:
MyApp.HD.Web.Controllers.RootController
MyApp.Web.Controllers.RootController
```

Why would I get this error on Azure but not locally? I can't figure out how to get around it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before. Let me explain why it happened.

We added a new project to our solution, let's call it `NewProject`. This project had been set up incorrectly so we recreated it as `NewProject2`. Once the project was setup and working, we renamed it to `NewProject`. This is when the problem started. Under certain build configurations we were getting the same error as you. It was complaining about ambiguous controllers with namespaces `NewProject` and `NewProject2`. Doing a find-in-files returned no matches for `NewProject2`. The was thoroughly frustrating. Given that this was only occuring under certain build configurations was a big sign that the problem was with *left-over* references in the bin folder(s). Doing a clean didn't seem to fix the problem. The ultimate fix was to do a complete code purge. DLLs typically do not get committed to source control. I backed up and deleted all code and got it back from source control. The issue no longer occurs.

It's worth mentioning that this issue was not global. It only occurred on certain developer machines. I figure the ones that were affect were the ones that had gotten latest from source control during the process of create1/create2/rename2/delete1.

1. Try doing a clean and rebuild in the affected build config.
2. Try manually removing your bin and obj folders.
3. Try a complete code purge

Comment: Ugh... I ended having to do a complete code purge. Thanks for the insights.